# Finding specific prime number

Tags: python, primes

Here is my implementation of finding a specific prime number:

```
import math

def checkPrime(i):
    if i == 3:
        return True;
    elif i == 2:
        return True;
    else:
        count = 2;
        prime = 2;
        
        while count <= math.sqrt(i):
            if (i % count == 0):
                prime += 1;
            count += 1;

        if prime == 2:
            return True;
        else:
            return False;

x = 0;
c = 2;
while x < 10001:
    if checkPrime(c) == True:
        print c;
        x += 1;
    c += 1;
```

I used this to find the 10,001st prime number (A problem I took from [Project Euclid](http://projecteuler.net/)). However, this doesn't seem to me to be an efficient way of solving the problem. It takes up a lot of computing power (evident from the fact that it takes around 20 seconds to finish executing). I solved this on my own, but the amount of time it takes is daunting.

What would be the most efficient way of accomplishing this problem?

P.S: I am printing out all the prime numbers to keep just see the out as a preference. It is not needed.

Comment: So... Is your question "Is there a better method, and if so what?"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @Dannnno Yes! Sorry I didn't clarify, edited.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: the fastest is `return list_of_all_primes[10001]` or simply `return 104743`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fast_primes(max_n):
    numbers = range(3, max_n+1, 2)
    half = (max_n)//2
    initial = 4

    for step in xrange(3, max_n+1, 2):
        for i in xrange(initial, half, step):
            numbers[i-1] = 0
        initial += 2*(step+1)

        if initial > half:
            return [2] + filter(None, numbers)
start = 5
tmp = []
while len(tmp) <  10001:
    tmp=fast_primes(start)
    start <<=1

print tmp[10001]
```

seems to be pretty fast to me (took 0.02 seconds on my marginal computer)

Comment: Wow! I just started solving problems on Eucler, and this is the first time I've had problems with execution time. I guess practical programming like these really open your eyes.
My implementation takes 40 seconds to execute, yours is amazingly quick. Goes to show how little knowledge of programming I have for now.

Comment: and to be fair this is optimized for finding the biggest prime that is less than some value ... Im sure you could speed it up with caching and optimizing around finding the nth prime instead